# Adding a UITextField to a UITableViewCell only shows a textField in the LAST cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a table view that has many cells. Each cell has its own UITextField. I added the text fields programmatically. I want each and every textField to appear when the edit button is hit. (now table is in edit mode) and when pressed again, i want all of the textFields to vanish(leaving the edit mode). I know that i can accomplish this using the `hidden` property, but i tried doing this in this method:

```
    - (IBAction)editButton:(id)sender 
{
    if (self.editing) 
    {
        [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [self.myTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        EditButton.title = @"Edit";
        cellText.hidden = YES;  //<-- THIS IS THE CODE
    } 
    else 
    {
        [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.myTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        EditButton.title = @"Done";
        cellText.hidden = NO;  //<-- THIS IS THE CODE
    }
}
```

but it only shows and hides the VERY LAST cell's textField. How can i get it to where it shows and then doesnt show EVERY cell's textFIeld? Many thanks in advance!!!

**CELL FOR ROW**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


         cellText = [[UITextField alloc]init];
         [cellText setFrame:CGRectMake(190, 15, 55, 30)];
         cellText.text = @"1";
         cellText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
         cellText.hidden = YES;
         cellText.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
         [cell addSubview:cellText];
    }    

return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance!! :D

Comment: You are making some mistake in code with cellForRowAtIndexPath method.And please make sure of passing the tag of every textField.Please post some code of that method.It will really help us to solve the issue.

Comment: alright! i will now! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

You can get rid of this issue, using this trick, I am not sure as if it would create the memory leak within your code.Since, it create new cell each time.But surely you can use it,if you don't get some proper way of doing it. ;)

```
- (IBAction)editButton:(id)sender 
{
 if (self.editing) 
        {
            [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
            [self.myTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
            EditButton.title = @"Edit";

        } 
        else 
        {
            [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
            [self.myTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
            EditButton.title = @"Done";

        }
        [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

After reloading the TableView, check the condition in cellForRowAtIndexPath, either pass the value of self.editing to TextField which makes it hide/show.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


    cellText = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    [cellText setFrame:CGRectMake(190, 15, 55, 30)];
    cellText.text = @"1";
    cellText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    cellText.hidden = YES;
    cellText.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cellText.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [cell addSubview:cellText];

    cellText.hidden=!self.editing;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks a bunch for the help! I inserted your code, and i still have the same problem... It only shows then hides the very last cell's textField. Is there anything else i could do? Thanks again!! +1

Comment: This is the working code for me.... Any how you can try to print the value of self.editing / BOOL , it should change accordingly.

Comment: hmm, this is weird. When i remove the [self.myTableView reloadData]; method, the textField Doesnt appear or dissapear at all. And when i do have the method, there is no animation when the tableView goes to and from editing mode, but when i remove it, the animation is nice. Thank you!

Comment: yes, you need to reload the tableView each time. And since you reload the tableview, each time it will create the new cells & there would be no animation, this is the drawback of the above code.But any how you would be able to solve your problem with above code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Although you create a text field for each cell, you keep a reference only to the last one in the ivar named `cellText`. That's why you show/hide the only text field.

I suggest you reload the table when toggling the editing mode, and set the text fields visibility in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Oh, and you should release `cellText` after adding it as a subview. Otherwise you are leaking memory. And it is highly recommended that you add subviews to `UITableViewCell` content view, rather than directly to the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! also, You said i keep a reference to the last textField in the ivar. How could i fix that? Also, i tried adding the [myTableView reloadData]; method to my editButton method and it just hides my animation when i try to set the table to and from the editing mode. It makes it all jerky! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
UITextField * cellText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 100, 30)];
cellText.tag = 1;
cellText.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
//cellText.numberOfLines = 0;
cellText.font = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica-Bold" size: 12.0 ] ; 
cellText.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor ] ;
cellText.text = @"123";
    cellText.hidden = YES;
[cell.contentView addSubview:cellText];
[cellText release];
cellText =nil;

// Set up the cell...


return cell;
}
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Detemine if it's in editing mode
  UITextField *cellText = (UITextField *)[[aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:1];
if (!self.editing) 
{
    [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
   // EditButton.title = @"Edit";

    cellText.hidden = YES;  //<-- THIS IS THE CODE
} 
else 
{
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
  //  EditButton.title = @"Done";
    cellText.hidden = NO;  //<-- THIS IS THE CODE
}

return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

hi friend this code is working fine for me, believe you too have a grate day

Comment: I think this code is helpful to you. I have this like of code in my app and its works well, all the best

Comment: i tied this code... however it still only shows the very last textField! Thank you for the help. Is there something i could be doing wrong? I have all the code correct!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually normal. Per the Apple documentation under addSubview:

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and
>   that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous
>   superview before making the receiver its new superview.

So it will keep removing it adding and removing from cells until it gets to the last one.

Comment: Obviously, a text field is created for every new cell.

Comment: Oh, right, I guess I thought since it was initializing to the same pointer it was still the same one just "resetting" essentially, but now that I look at it again (especially the other method) I understand. In that case your answer is definitely correct =D.